# DataFrame rolling with complex function

Tags: python, dataframe

Below is my quasi-code:

```
import pandas as pd

dict = {'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 
'b': [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 
'c': [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)

def make_coeff(x):
    a_new = x[0]
    b_new = x[1]
    c_new = x[2]
    
    a_new.insert(0,1)
    b_new[0] = 1
    c_new[0] = 1
    
    return array_value(a_new, b_new, c_new)
    
df['array_col'] = df.rolling(3)[['a','b','c']].apply(make_coeff)
```

I want to create new col `array_col` depending on the rolling window with following actions:

insert 1 to a at beginning; change b[0] = c[0] = 1

use row 2 as an example:

row 2: a = [3,2,1], b = [4,3,2], c = [5,4,3] # 3 rolling window from row 2

row 2: a_new = [1,3,2,1], b_new = [1,3,2], c_new = [1,4,3] # action on each column

row 2 of `array_col`: array_value(a_new, b_new, c_new) # return a array value

here `array_value` is a known function returning an multi-dimensional array value. Let's assume it is a tensor product between all vectors with shape `(len(a), len(b), len(c))`:

```
def array_value(a, b ,c):
    tem = np.tensordot(a,b, axis=0)
    tem = np.tensordot(tem,c, axis=0)
    
    return tem
```

Comment: hi sorry what is `array_value()?`

Comment: @Mark no, the action for a_new is insert 1 at begin, which is different with b and c. So it should be [1,3,2,1]

Comment: okay, I think think I understand now

Comment: have you tried debugging the code? I am currently in debug mode. On the line `a_new.insert(0,1)`, a_new = `1.0`, b_new `2.0`, c_new = `3.0`. I'm guessing that's not what you had in mind

Comment: @Mark not work, even I change to the simple return a_new[0] + b_new[0] + c_new[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict = {'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 
'b': [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 
'c': [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)


# create an array column of the rolling values of column a
df['a_rolling'] = [window.to_list() for window in df['a'].rolling(window=3)]
df['b_rolling'] = [window.to_list() for window in df['b'].rolling(window=3)]
df['c_rolling'] = [window.to_list() for window in df['c'].rolling(window=3)]

def make_coeff(a, b, c):
    if len(a) < 3:
        return [0,0,0] # the first couple of rows obviously don't have enough values
    # insert 0,1 at the beginning of a
    a = np.insert(a, 0, 0)
    b[0] = 1
    c[0] = 1
    
    return array_value(a, b, c)

def array_value(a, b ,c):
    tem = np.tensordot(a, b, axes=0)
    tem = np.tensordot(tem, c, axes=0)
    
    return tem

df['coeff'] = df.apply(lambda x: make_coeff(x['a_rolling'], x['b_rolling'], x['c_rolling']), axis=1)
```

This is likely not precisely what you want, but it is something

Comment: so we have to create the rolling columns rather than working in rolling.apply directly？

Comment: I mean, if you find some way of doing it, then you can do it, I just haven't found a way of doing it

Comment: up to now, it is the only way working for my